# How to send gpg encrypted file to a specific folder in just one commandline?

Tags: gnupg

I need to execute a commandline like this:

```
C:\>gpg --output criticalToAdam2.gpg --encrypt --recipient 08C683ca critical.docx
```

To a specific folder, for example: `MyHappyFolder\AnotherFolder`

How can I accomplish that without more than one command line, like "`cd MyHappyFolder\AnotherFolder`" ?

Comment: Does adding the filepath not work properly? Like *C:\ > gpg --output MyHappyFolder\AnotherFolder\criticalToAdam2.gpg --encrypt --recipient 08C683ca critical.docx* . Gotta ask the obvious questions first.

Comment: sorry not to mention the obvious, it is always good to be clear. Yes I tried that from the beginning, it doesnt work, thanks

Comment: Would creating a script work for your situation? You could have batch file that CD's and then runs the gpg command.

Comment: I checked that in Linux, both full and relative paths work just fine with `--output`. Perhaps this is a windows issue? Try full paths, and try `/`-s instead of `\\`-s. If all fails, add a windows tag. :D

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer might be found [here](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2007-October/031853.html), and it involves problems with Posix to Win32 path conversion. Instead of `MyHappyFolder\AnotherFolder`, try:

```
MyHappyFolder/AnotherFolder
MyHappyFolder\\AnotherFolder
"MyHappyFolder\AnotherFolder"
"MyHappyFolder\\AnotherFolder"
```

Answer (score 1):

Encrypt with password:

```
gpg -o /tmp/Linux.pdf.gpg -c Linux.pdf
```

Encrypt with key:

```
gpg -o /tmp/Linux.pdf.gpg -e -r "UID_or_Email" Linux.pdf
```